# How to get current currency symbol in multi-currencies magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, currency, multicurrency

I am trying to show item price with symbol in override email template on order create, and my site have **euro and $ both currency.**

Is there any way to get `current currency symbol`, Please share if have.

Comment: `protected $this->storeManage;

\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManage

$this->storeManage = $storeManage

$this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();`

Comment: protected causes error

Comment: what you mean by `current currency symbol`

Comment: current currency symbol means when I am going to create a order by backend. There is dropdown to select currency for order,

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$priceHelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
$priceHelper->currency($YOURPRICE, true, false);
```

Maybe it will help you.

Comment: It is working fine for euro....But when switching to $ price is coming in round figure

Answer (score 1):

I donot know,what extract you want.

In magento, whenever a system have multiple currencies means system have **a base currency and have multiple currencies**.  And **multiple currencies manage via rate,**

Then whensoever an  order placed at system and  **then base currency and order place time currency both codes** are save **at order table `sales_order`.**

You can find

**base currency code** from  `base_currency_code field`

**order time currency code** from `order_currency_code`

Comment: Actully amit, I override a email template where I need to show item price, priceFormatter($_item->getPrice()) by this price is coming but in round,  like 0.73 will be 8

Answer (score 1):

**Currency code and symbol:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currencysymbol= $objectManager
->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currencyCode = $currencysymbol->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$currency  = $objectManager
->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')
->create()->load($currencyCode);
$currencySymbol= $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
```

**Simple way to get price with currency**

```
$this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency($price,true,false); //$price is final amount
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the Currency Symbol :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');

$price =  1000; //Your Price

$formattedPrice = $priceHelper->currency($price, true, false);
```